# Ajax results back to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to send the results of the current drag drop state back to mysql  using ajax/php.

The console .log works fine..

With some help the drag and drop jquery feature is all working perfectly however sadly jquery/ajax is really not in my bag of tricks ..

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/FMKmj/ (Credit mu)

Tearing my hair out , any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to submit the groups hash, do it like:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var groups = { };
    $('.sort').each(function() {
        var a = [ ];
        $(this).find('li').each(function() {
            a.push(this.id);
        });
        groups[this.id] = a;
    });
    console.log(groups);

   $.ajax({
    url: "yourscript.php",
    data: groups,
    success: function(){
      alert('sent!');
    }
  });   

});
```

Comment: uhm.. `this.id` does return the id of the DOM Element. It's like `document.getElementById("mydiv").id` will return mydiv if found.

Comment: When you say it,I see what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1: Catch the event

Notice that in the JQuery UI doc for sortable there is an event tab: [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/).
So you have to bind an event to an Ajax call inside the event handling function called when a block is dropped in a new box.

### Step 2: The Ajax call

It means you have to write your Ajax call: [see here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).
Typically, you will do a post request since moving a block from a place to another place will change something on the server side.
What do you send to the server ?
Basically you want to send to the server which block has moved where. But it is up to you, you can send whatever you want, it depends on you server side application.

### Step 3: The server side

The server based on this information can execute MySQL requests.